# Python: add '\' to int in order to display a letter

Tags: python, escaping, ascii, concatenation

The question is simple. I have a txt file with ASCII codes that I want to display as a readable English text. In order to do so, I've parsed it into a list of integers (let's call it l) with integers. so that '\l[0]' displays '*' if l[0] = 42.

What I have trouble doing is to add an escape to the integer, for instant '\' + 'l[0]' is invalid because Python understands as "I try to escape the quote but I couldn't find the ending quote" and if I do '\'+ 'l[0]', I'll indeed see '\42' on screen, because the first backslash escapes the second and there is no escaping in the last expression.

So the question is how could one add a backslash as escape character to another string?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just escape the backslash - `print '\\' + str(l[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have converted the ASCII codes to integers, just use `chr` to display them.

```
for c in l:
    sys.stdout.write(chr(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would find [chr() built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of integers you can directly display corresponding `ascii` characters using chr() method as:

```
>>> l=range(33,128)
>>> for i in l: print chr(i),
... 
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
```

This way you don't need to add `'\'` to any integer to display its character.